# Kwikset deadbolt rust prevention

Tags: rust-proofing

I purchased several [Kwikset deadbolts](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Kwikset-Satin-Nickel-Single-Cylinder-Deadbolt-featuring-SmartKey-Security-with-Microban-Antimicrobial-Technology-98015SMTCPK4V1/309567384) and they are rusting / corroding in the outer ring (not stainless steel), not the locking mechanism.  Items are installed on a Florida island.  Would rubbing a thin coat of oil or similar lubricant slow down the rusting of the outer ring?

[image]

Would a vegetable oil or olive be just as effective as motor oil / WD40?  An line of reason or lessons learned are appreciated.

Or would a spray on [clear enamel be more effective](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koj8741TzqY)?  The outer perimeter ring (workpiece that is rusting) can be separated from the locking mechanism, so as to avoid gumming up locking mechanism

Thank you

Comment: If motor oil or WD40 don’t work, you know you can order stainless steel Schlage hardware with stainless steel guts. I’m not sure about Kwikset.

Comment: A good seal will also help.  There shouldn't be much moisture in the lock body, even if you live up here in canada.  The externals should already be coated.  Has internal rust been a problem for you before?

Comment: Do not use vegetable oils. They have proteins and watter and will gotten over time and cause rust. Tung oil  or boiled linseed oil is good. WD-40 good for cleaning, not lubrication.

Comment: It has moving parts,  you may destroy it with enamel.

Comment: Where in the lock are you experiencing rust - on the exterior or in the interior? It may determine the best preventative measure.

Comment: Where are you located?   I wouldn't expect to see this problem unless either the lock is el cheapo or you're in a coastal (salt fog) environment.

Comment: That looks like stainless steel, (or possibly nickel plated,)  why are you expecting it to fail?

Comment: I don't know if it is a good idea but I have seen the outer protective cover of a deadbolt be painted the same color as the front door

Comment: I'd be contacting my retailer due to the **Lifetime mechanical and finish warranty** listed on the page you linked.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues at my sister's Florida condo. Had to replace a ton of hardware due to corrosion. All hardware (exterior and interior) rusts or degrades there due to marine environs.

I would contact Kwikset and request replacement trim rings or whatever has gone bad. Do NOT spray anything into/onto lockset. You'll just have a worse situation. No oils or corrosion sprays. Or replace the whole lockset.

Stainless steel would be very expensive.

Kwikset would not be my first choice.... Bargain Schlage as sold in the stores didn't survive this moisture onslaught either.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mineral oil (not a food oil) to protect the out side. Then you can re-oil from time to time. Food oils tend to oxidize and gel over time. The interior components are catch 22 ; WD 40 type oil will protect from corrosion but will collect dust and dirt and may eventually interfere with operation. Stainless would help but would need to be type 316 , manufacturer may not give this info. I have not seen locks with internal stainless components , but I never looked. Sea coast corrosion (salt) is difficult to stop.